# Sorting a string in mips?

Tags: string, sorting, mips

I am trying to sort a string that is entered by the user. Is there any way to access a specific element of that string? Here is my mips code:

```
.data
prompt: .asciiz "\n\nEnter an string of characters: "
result: .asciiz "\n\nHere is the string you entered: "
buffer: .space 20
.text

main:
li $v0, 4 #code for printing a string
la $a0, prompt 
syscall 

li $v0, 8 #code for reading a string
la $a0, buffer
li $a1, 80
syscall

li $v0, 4 #code for printing a string
la $a0, result 
syscall

la $a0, buffer #code for printing a string
li $v0, 4
syscall
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access a specific byte (character) of the string using `lb`. This will load the character in a register, to be used in your sorting algorithm.